# set php session timeout by user

Tags: php, session, timeout

It´s possible to set session timeout by user in php?

Example: 2 users are registred in my site. I want that each user can set their own session timeout.

Comment: Related: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can set a custom session timeout for each user. You can use the method as described in [*How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960) but store the absolute expiration time instead:

```
// set expiration time
$_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + $customSessionLifetime;

// validate session
if (isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) && (time() < $_SESSION['EXPIRES'])) {
    // session still valid; update expiration time
    $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + $customSessionLifetime;
} else {
    // session invalid or expired
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}
```

Here `$customSessionLifetime` can be set differently for each user. Just make sure that its value is less than or equal to *session.gc_maxlifetime* and *session.cookie_lifetime* (if you use a cookie for the session ID).